# Ansible fails to connect with ssh but I can (using ssh key)

Tags: ssh, ansible

Im trying to get started with Ansible, but am getting stuck at what appears to be a common problem - yet I cannot find the solution.

When I run `ansible -vvvvvvvvvvv all -m ping` ansible fails with the following. Im not sure exactly why ansible is unable to ping.

My ansible hosts file contains:

```
[prod3]
xx.xxx.xx.xxx ansible_ssh_user=john ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have also tried just:

```
[prod3]
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

I am able to do `ssh root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx` without any problems from the same computer.

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User=user)
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/john/.ansible/cp/3cba3e6666)
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/john/.ansible/cp/3cba3e6666 xx.xxx.xx.xxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<xx.xxx.xx.xxx> (255, '', 'OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket "/home/john/.ansible/cp/3cba3e6666" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving "xx.xxx.xx.xxx" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9691 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa type 1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to xx.xxx.xx.xxx:22 as \'user\'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/john/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:14\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xxx.xx.xxx\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:iKFbjnxi+V1oXMbOxz4gwIwIuGoGkQa5rMFdeyMe8F4\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/john/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:14\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xxx.xx.xxx\r\ndebug1: Host \'xx.xxx.xx.xxx\' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:14\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa (0x556707a76500), agent\r\ndebug2: key: GitLab (0x556707a792d0), agent\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: GitLab\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n')
xx.xxx.xx.xxx | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/john/.ansible/cp/3cba3e6666\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"xx.xxx.xx.xxx\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9691 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa type 1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to xx.xxx.xx.xxx:22 as 'user'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/home/john/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:14\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xxx.xx.xxx\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:iKFbjnxi+V1oXMbOxz4gwIwIuGoGkQa5rMFdeyMe8F4\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/home/john/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:14\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xxx.xx.xxx\r\ndebug1: Host 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:14\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa (0x556707a76500), agent\r\ndebug2: key: GitLab (0x556707a792d0), agent\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: GitLab\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

In my ansible host file I had:

```
[prod3]
xx.xxx.xx.xxx ansible_ssh_user=john ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But instead I should have had

```
[prod3]
xx.xxx.xx.xxx ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I was specifying the local user, rather than remote.